# Bootstrap Navigation Bar Alignment Issue with Burger Dropdown

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a navigation bar using Bootstrap.
I tried adding `ml-auto` to the button, but it didn't do anything.
I'm expecting the burger icon to be on the right but it's just right next to the logo.

Gyazo Link: https://gyazo.com/5e43976fa856dcc2a807ff93d612c989

**My HTML**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- My Own Sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">

    <title>LevelUpIRL</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="logo.png" width="300" height="60"</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
      aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Log In</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**My CSS File**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li, a {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: #edf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**Code from Bootstrap Website**

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IMG tag is not closed in your code inside A tag.

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="logo.png" width="300" height="60"</a>
```

It should be as below::

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="logo.png" width="300" height="60"></a>
```

Comment: OMG. Thanks so much. Ugh that was dumb.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do any thing just your mistake is that you are not complete the logo image tag `>` is missing. so it was not structure of your page properly. please complete your image tag and try your code.

Or you can put this snippet html code.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li, a {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: #edf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
      <img src="logo.png" width="300" height="60">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
    aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Log In</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the img tag in your logo. Close it and it will fix it.

Change it from

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="logo.png" width="300" height="60"</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="logo.png" width="300" height="60"></a>
```